# C#(.net)のjsonデータのデシリアライズについて

Tags: c#, .net, json

C#のJsonデータのデシリアライズについての質問となります。
連番された項目名のオブジェクトをListにしてデシリアライズする良い方法がないか、調査中です。
良い方法があれば、ご教授して頂ければと思います。

**前提**
例えば、これまでは下記のような一部が配列となるjsonを処理する必要があり、

```
{
    "textData": "textVal",
    "numData" : 123,
    "objData": [
        {
            "hogeText": "hogeTextVal1",
            "hogeNum" : 1,
            "hogeobj": {
                "hoge": "hogeVal1",
                "hage": "hageVal1"
            }
        },
        {
            "hogeText": "hogeTextVal2",
            "hogeNum" : 2,
            "hogeobj": {
                "hoge": "hogeVal2",
                "hage": "hageVal2"
            }
        },
        {
            "hogeText": "hogeTextVal3",
            "hogeNum" : 3,
            "hogeobj": {
                "hoge": "hogeVal3",
                "hage": "hageVal3"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

下記Entityクラスを準備して、「JsonSerializer.Deserialize(json);」(namespace: System.Text.Json)でデシリアライズを行っていました。
※課題が解決できれば、デシリアライズの方法にこだわりはありません。

```
public class entity
{
    public class Root
    {
        public string textData { get; set; }

        public long numData { get; set; }

        public ObjDatum[] objData { get; set; }
    }

    public class ObjDatum
    {
        public string hogeText { get; set; }

        public long hogeNum { get; set; }

        public Hogeobj hogeobj { get; set; }
    }

    public class Hogeobj
    {
        public string hoge { get; set; }

        public string hage { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**質問**
前提のような一部配列のjsonではなく、下記のようにオブジェクト名が連番で変動するデータの場合、前提と同様にデシリアライズ時にListにする方法はありますか。
(前提の配列objData部が、objData1、objData2、objData3...ようになる)

```
{
    "textData": "textVal",
    "numData" : 123,
    "objData1": {
        "hogeText": "hogeTextVal1",
        "hogeNum" : 1,
        "hogeobj1": {
            "hoge": "hogeVal1",
            "hage": "hageVal1"
        }
    },
    "objData2": {
        "hogeText": "hogeTextVal2",
        "hogeNum" : 2,
        "hogeobj2": {
            "hoge": "hogeVal2",
            "hage": "hageVal2"
        }
    },
    "objData3": {
        "hogeText": "hogeTextVal3",
        "hogeNum" : 3,
        "hogeobj3": {
            "hoge": "hogeVal3",
            "hage": "hageVal3"
        }
    }
}
```

実際には3つだけではなく、数10、数100というobjDataがあるため、1つずつクラスを作成する方法は避けたいと思っています。
また、ネストされたhogeobjも連番で項目名が変動いたします。デシリアライズされた後にListをさらに処理・加工するため、プロパティ名は揃っていて欲しいです。

以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

構成が複雑なので、ある程度ゴリ押しのコードで達成することになると予想しています。
私が思いついた方法は以下の2つです。

1. [JsonDocument](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsondocument?view=netcore-3.0)でネストを深掘りする方法

- サンプルコードの`ParseElephant`メソッドです

2. [JsonExtensionDataAttribute](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonextensiondataattribute?view=netcore-3.0)である程度動的に値を取得する方法

- サンプルコードの`ParseClass`メソッドです

Json内部で入れ子になっているJsonを[JsonConverter](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconverter?view=netcore-3.0)でカスタム変換できれば良かったのですが、動的な名称の項目に適用する方法が見つかりませんでした。

**サンプルコード**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ParseElephant();
            ParseClass();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// JsonDocumentを使いながらJsonを深掘りしてプロパティを補完する手法
        /// </summary>
        private static void ParseElephant()
        {
            // objData 以外をざっくり作成
            Root root = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Root>(JSON_TEXT);
            var doc = JsonDocument.Parse(JSON_TEXT);
            root.objData = doc.RootElement.EnumerateObject()
                .Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith("objData"))     // Jsonキーが "objData" から始まるもの
                .Select(elm =>
                {
                    // Rootと同様に hogeobj 以外をざっくり作成
                    ObjDatum objDatum = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ObjDatum>(elm.Value.GetRawText());
                    // 上のLinqと同様の深掘り手法
                    using var hogeDoc = JsonDocument.Parse(elm.Value.GetRawText());
                    var prop = hogeDoc.RootElement.EnumerateObject()
                                .First(x => x.Name.StartsWith("hogeobj"));    // Jsonキーが "hogeobj" から始まるもの
                    objDatum.hogeobj = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Hogeobj>(prop.Value.GetRawText());
                    return objDatum;
                })
                .ToList();
            Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize<Root>(root));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// クラスメソッドからJsonSerializerを呼び出してプロパティを補完する手法
        /// </summary>
        private static void ParseClass()
        {
            using var doc = JsonDocument.Parse(JSON_TEXT);
            var root = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Root2>(JSON_TEXT);
            //プロパティは正しく取れる
            Console.WriteLine(root.ObjData[0].hogeobj.hoge);
            //シリアライズすると求めるフォーマットから離れる
            Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize<Root2>(root));
        }

        const string JSON_TEXT = @"{
    ""textData"": ""textVal"",
    ""numData"" : 123,
    ""objData1"": {
        ""hogeText"": ""hogeTextVal1"",
        ""hogeNum"" : 1,
        ""hogeobj1"": {
            ""hoge"": ""hogeVal1"",
            ""hage"": ""hageVal1"" 
        }
    },
    ""objData2"": {
        ""hogeText"": ""hogeTextVal2"",
        ""hogeNum"" : 2,
        ""hogeobj2"": {
            ""hoge"": ""hogeVal2"",
            ""hage"": ""hageVal2"" 
        }
    },
    ""objData3"": {
        ""hogeText"": ""hogeTextVal3"",
        ""hogeNum"" : 3,
        ""hogeobj3"": {
            ""hoge"": ""hogeVal3"",
            ""hage"": ""hageVal3"" 
        }
    }
}";
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public string textData { get; set; }

        public long numData { get; set; }

        public List<ObjDatum> objData { get; set; }
    }

    public class ObjDatum
    {
        public string hogeText { get; set; }

        public long hogeNum { get; set; }

        public Hogeobj hogeobj { get; set; }
    }

    public class Hogeobj
    {
        public string hoge { get; set; }

        public string hage { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root2
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("textData")]
        public string TextData { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("numData")]
        public long NumData { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnoreAttribute]
        public List<ObjDatum2> ObjData
        {
            get
            {
                return ExtensionData.Values
                  .Select(v => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ObjDatum2>(v.GetRawText())).ToList();
            }
        }

        [JsonExtensionDataAttribute]
        public IDictionary<string, JsonElement> ExtensionData { get; set; }
    }

    public class ObjDatum2
    {
        public string hogeText { get; set; }

        public long hogeNum { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnoreAttribute]
        public Hogeobj hogeobj
        {
            get
            {
                return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Hogeobj>(ExtensionData.Values.First().GetRawText());
            }
        }

        [JsonExtensionDataAttribute]
        public IDictionary<string, JsonElement> ExtensionData { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**出力結果**

```
{"textData":"textVal","numData":123,"objData":[{"hogeText":"hogeTextVal1","hogeNum":1,"hogeobj":{"hoge":"hogeVal1","hage":"hageVal1"}},{"hogeText":"hogeTextVal2","hogeNum":2,"hogeobj":{"hoge":"hogeVal2","hage":"hageVal2"}},{"hogeText":"hogeTextVal3","hogeNum":3,"hogeobj":{"hoge":"hogeVal3","hage":"hageVal3"}}]}
hogeVal1
{"textData":"textVal","numData":123,"objData1":{"hogeText":"hogeTextVal1","hogeNum":1,"hogeobj1":{"hoge":"hogeVal1","hage":"hageVal1"}},"objData2":{"hogeText":"hogeTextVal2","hogeNum":2,"hogeobj2":{"hoge":"hogeVal2","hage":"hageVal2"}},"objData3":{"hogeText":"hogeTextVal3","hogeNum":3,"hogeobj3":{"hoge":"hogeVal3","hage":"hageVal3"}}}
```

前者の`ParseElephant`は冗長ですが、再度Jsonにシリアライズした時にobjDataはきれいな配列になります。
後者の`ParseClass`の方が一見コードはきれいに見えますし、プロパティの値は問題なく取得できますが、Jsonにシリアライズすると動的なキー名称はそのままです。

Answer (score 1):

payanecoさんもおっしゃっている通りスッキリした書き方はできませんね。

[オーバーフロー JSON の処理](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to#handle-overflow-json)という機能を使うと対応するプロパティのない要素を`Dictionary`として取得することができます。これを利用して、次のようにクラス定義します。

```
public class Root{
    public string textData { get; set; }
    public long numData { get; set; }

    [JsonExtensionData]
    public Dictionary<string, JsonElement> ExtensionData { private get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, ObjDatum> objData
        => ExtensionData.ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ObjDatum>(p.Value.GetRawText()));
}

public class ObjDatum {
    public string hogeText { get; set; }
    public long hogeNum { get; set; }
    public Hogeobj hogeobj { get; set; }
}

public class Hogeobj {
    public string hoge { get; set; }
    public string hage { get; set; }
}
```

`ExtensionData` という不要なプロパティが見えてしまいますが、 `objData` プロパティを参照すると再度デシリアライズして `Dictionary<string, ObjDatum>` を得ることができます。